# Recursive Function Help - Java

Tags: java, function, recursion

I'm new here.
I got a problem with a recursive function in Java.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(f(3));
}

private static int f(int n) {
    if (n<=0) return 1;
    return 2*f(n-1)+3; 
}
```

If I set `n = 3`, the result is `29`.
Please help, I don't understand the result, it would be really nice,
if anybody can exactly explain what is going on in this function.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. It will be useful in many more cases.

Comment: Do you understand the result for n = 1 and n = 2?

Comment: The Debugger in Netbeans didnt help me in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning to trace the execution of a recursive function helps you create ones in future. It's an important skill to develop.

Let's do a trace.

Each recursive function has an "exit condition", or "base case". In your function, it is when n<=0. You passed in 3, so the result would be:

2*f(2) + 3

What is f(2)?
2*f(1) + 3

What is f(1)?
2*f(0) +3

We know that f(0) is 1 because that's your base case, so now work backwards and fill out the following table:

```
f(0): 1
f(1): 2*1 + 3 = 5
f(2): 2*5 + 3 = 13
f(3): 2*13 + 3 = 29
```

Comment: Amazing explanation, thank you very much :)                                            The Debugger in Netbeans didnt help me anyway, it didnt show me the results step by step :(

Answer (score 3):

Look at the method

```
private static int f(int n) {
    if (n<=0) return 1;
    return 2*f(n-1)+3; 
}
```

at first, `f(3)` will be called

method returns `2*f(2)+3`

to calculate `f(2)` method needs to return `2*f(1)+3`

`f(1)` will be calculated as `2*f(0)+3`

`f(0)` is `1` by condition `n<=0`, so let it back track

```
2*1+3 = 5 = f(1)
2*5+3 = 13 = f(2)
2*13+3 = 29 = f(3)
```

Comment: Your explanation is almost the same as mine but more concise.

Answer (score 1):

f(0) is 1.

You get the next number by doubling the previous one and adding 3.

So the sequence is 1, 5, 13, 29, 61, etc.

Solving this by recursion is not the best way (your stack will overflow for quite small terms); a normal loop would be better.